# Unknown host exception for 127.0.0.1 in RabbitMQ client

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a very strange exception in my application. `127.0.0.1` is unknown host. I don't know how it can happened. Below details:

```
ShardedAmqpSpout [WARN] Failed to reconnect to AMQP broker
  java.net.UnknownHostException: 127.0.0.1
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:588)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:612)
    at pl.mbank.storm.amqp.ShardedAmqpSpout.setupAMQP(ShardedAmqpSpout.java:220)
    at pl.mbank.storm.amqp.ShardedAmqpSpout.reconnect(ShardedAmqpSpout.java:239)
    at pl.mbank.storm.amqp.ShardedAmqpSpout.open(ShardedAmqpSpout.java:201)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3985$fn__3997.invoke(executor.clj:460)
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:375)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Well, that's weird ! Did you check your loopback interface with `ping 127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: ping, nslookup are looking good

Comment: Check your /etc/hosts file if on linux /osx or the equivalent on other OSes - sometimes they go missing - if not present add this entry and restart networking.
127.0.0.1       localhost

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I have absolutely the same problem but with external hosts

Comment: @Antonio I don't remember :(

Answer (score 0):

Clear the space before and after 127.0.0.1.  I'v fixed with this.